# Magento 2: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: magento2

I am getting this error.
A non well formed numeric value encountered in

**/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml on line 197**

using this code on **list.phtml**

```
round($productPrice / $areaprsqft, 2);
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Please check for space between or after the numerical values, If any please remove them.

Comment: I removed the space as found the solution. But again getting this error.

Comment: Can you show the line please ?

Comment: I am using this code on list.phtml round($productPrice / $areaprsqft, 2);

Comment: Please try this $newPrice = $productPrice / $areaprsqft; round($newPrice, 2);

Comment: @Shiwani => Try  round(($productPrice / $areaprsqft), 2);